# Nop Commerce Show Associated Product Specification Attribute Separately

Tags: nopcommerce

I am using Nop Commerce platform To display Electronic Products.
I have a grouped product and under which there are two associated Products.
I have difference in some of the Specification Attributes of these two Simple Products.
When I add the Specification Attribute to these simple products they do not appear under the product.
Is there any property that I am missing?

Comment: What version of NopCommerce are u running?

Comment: I am using 3.2 version.The latest one.